# C#: Fill DataGridView with DataTable creates empty table

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I searched the web and Stack Overflow and found lots of descriptions on how to fill a DataGridView with the content of a DataTable. But still it does not work for me. My DataGridView shows the correct number of columns and rows, but they appear empty.

I use following method:

```
public void ShowDataInGrid(ref DataTable table)
    {
        BindingSource sBind = new BindingSource();
        dbView.Columns.Clear();
        dbView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        sBind.DataSource = table;
        dbView.DataSource = sBind;    //Add table to DataGridView
        dbView.Columns.Add("Date", "Date");            
    }
```

Before this I created  a DataGridView of name "dbView" via the designer. I am not even sure, whether I need sBind. Without it I can bind the table directly to dbView, with the same bad result.

I suspect my table is the problem. It origins from a database (SQLite) and has several columns and rows (one of the columns has the name "Date"). It is definately filled with readable data.
I mainly read the table in using following commands (after this I manipulate the data in several different steps, like changing strings and adding numbers...):

```
        string sql = "select * from Bank";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        table.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        table.AcceptChanges();
```

I think the problem might be, that the table entries are stored as objects and not as string, and hence can't be shown. That's why I tried to force the content to be strings with the following change to my table:

```
DataTable dbTableClone = new DataTable();
dbTableClone.Load(reader);
SQLiteDataReader reader.Close();
dbTableClone.AcceptChanges();

string[] dBHeader = new string[dbTableClone.Columns.Count];
dBHeader = ReadHeaderFromDataTable(dbTableClone); //own funktion, which reads the header
DataTable table;
table.Clear();
//will first create dbTable as empty clone, so I can set DataTyp of each Column
table = dbTableClone.Clone(); 
for (int col = 0; col > dBHeader.Length; col++) //first set all columns as string
{
   dbTable.Columns[col].DataType = typeof(string);
}
foreach (DataRow Row in dbTableClone.Rows)
{
   dbTable.ImportRow(Row);
}
```

This did not help me neither.
Another idea: I found some comments on similar problems, where it got apparently solved with quote: "I designed columns in the VS datagridview designer. Not the column name, but the column DataPropertyName must match with fields in database." Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to do/understand this.

Following you see one row of my input table.

[image]

Comment: Can you define your problem in short and precise?

Comment: DataViewTable shows a table with the correct number of rows (same as bound table) but without content. Each Cell is empty.

Comment: Have you seen that table has data after execution of the query?`table.Load(reader);`

Comment: Yes table certainly has data. Following command fills singleRowContent:       singleRowContent[row] = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[row][0]);     However I need the "Convert" otherwise I get an error: singleRowContent[row] = FDBHandler.dbable.Rows[row][0]; (cannot implicitly convert type object to string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The DataTable was fine. The problem was the setup of my DataGridView dbView. I set up dbView in the designer and somehow gave it a datasource. Now I set the datasource to "none" (In "DataGridView Tasks") and my data appears as intended.
Thanks to M Adeel Khalid for looking at my stuff. Him assuring to me that my code for the link was right, made me find the solution eventually.
At the end I really only needed to  use a single line:

```
dbView.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching and setting to GridView this way

```
        SqlLiteConnection con = new SqlLiteConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlLiteDataAdapter adap = new SqlLiteDataAdapter("select * from Bank", con);
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment everything you've done so far, try this and let me know if this works for you or not. Change connection according to your DB.

Comment: I've created a new test() with exactly your code. Only thing I needed to change was @"Data Source= **test.sqlite** ;AttachDbFilename=DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"); --> ds gets filled ( can see it in the debug mode), but dataGridView1 is not filled (not even with empty cells). --> I added dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Date", "Date"); This way I get again Cells into the view, but they are still empty.

Comment: Can you share the structure and data of your table within some snap?

Comment: Ok I added a snapshot of one row of my data table to the original post.

Comment: The problem is your values not the code of getting and setting to the grid. You might need to save them correctly or fetch them correctly before setting the `datasource` of grid. When you fill up the `dataset`, make a `for loop` over it, get all the columns and see what their value is and set the corrected value i.e. convert them to whatever format you wish and finally set the `gridView1.datasource=ds`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts. I also suspected the values inside the datatable to be the problem. I will have a closer look at this again. (I alreade tried to cast them as a string into the datatable)

Comment: I looked again for a while into the data type in the cells of my datatable. They contain "object {string}" even after I just added a new string into a fresh cell. Is "object {string}" the same as string or is this my problem? How can I get rid of this. No matter how I feed my DataTable I get the same result.

Comment: This is not a good practice of storing such values in the db, I would suggest you to correct your db. It is better to avoid writing so much code instead of correcting the fault at db end.